# Data Replication from HANA to HANA

Tags: hana, database-replication, slt

I need to replicate data from a source HANA database to other HANA database on real time basis (on trigger event like update/delete/insert). I have searched for the solution and found one i.e. SAP LT Replication Server.

But I need custom implementation like taking data from source HANA database and putting in a queue. Is it possible? And need some suggestions regarding SAP LT Replication Server.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty broad, so I recommend to familiarize yourself more with the use case and the available technology.
Besides SAP LT replication, you could potentially use the Smart Streaming option to facilitate real-time data transfer.

However, database level real-time replication is a rather specific requirement and can easily be confused with more general integration requirements. Be very careful about the application level you integrate your applications on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SAP HANA EIM Smart Data Integration. The HANA adapter is trigger based, supports real time scenarios including DDL propagation.
Within the target HANA DB you would create a reptask or a realtime flow-graph.
You can find the details in the Administration Guide for SAP HANA Smart Data Integration and SAP HANA Smart Data Quality.